# vim color not loaded or not working

Tags: macos, vim

I'm a fresh vim user, and I want to try new color themes.
I created a .vim dir which contains colors dir with themes and .vimrc file, and I created a symlink in my home dir, it is points to ./vim/.vimrc file.

Here is my .vimrc:

```
syntax enable
set t_Co=256
set synmaxcol=240
set background=dark
colorscheme twilight
let g:solarized_termcolors=256
```

This is the screenshot:
 [image]
and that's what I want:
 [image]

Whats wrong?

**Note:**
If I use the graphical macvim, it works, so something wrong with in my terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The `let g:solarized_termcolors=256` is only useful if you use the solarized colorscheme. Since you want to use twilight, this line is useless and should be removed.
2. The twilight theme is GUI-only. Its colors are defined with hex values which are only understood by MacVim/GVim. It won't work in the terminal, no matter what you do. You can use [twilight256](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3436) instead, which is designed for color terminals.

Answer (score 0):

The vim themes, define a separate set of colors for the GUI (i.e. `gvim`) and the terminal (i.e. `vim`), hence you might end up seeing different colors in gvim vs vim. The reason behind that is the limited number of colors supported in the terminal compared to GUI.

#### CSApprox

But you could use a plugin like [CSApprox](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2390), which will convert the colors in the GUI colorscheme to an equivalent one for terminal such that you see almost the similar set of colors. Most modern terminals (like Gnome Terminal, Console, OSX Terminal) that support 88 or 256 colors should work fine with this plugin.

The good thing about the `CSApprox` plugin is not separate configuration is necessary, and merely having this plugin in your `.vim` directory is good enough. And when you run the `colorscheme` command to choose a color scheme, this plugin automatically converts the colors for you as long as your terminal supports 88 or 256 colors.

And if you're running `gvim` or the terminal does not support 88/256 colors, this plugin just merely remains silent without doing any color conversions. And there is a mechanism to export the converted colors too I believe.

#### Alternative

Another similar plugin that I've heard is [guicolorscheme](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1809) which is similar to `CSApprox`, but you need to set the color scheme using the command `:GuiColorScheme <color scheme name>`.